# How to make player node stand after jump in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I create a physics body for player (orc) from the texture.

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: player.texture!.size())
player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
player.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategoryBitmask.Player
player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
player.physicsBody?.friction = 1
ground?.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
```

[image]

and the jump action is created by applying impulse

```
 func jumpPlayer(){
    player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 60))
 }
```

After the jump, once landed the player node seems to be off the balance and falls down.

[image]

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by making allowsRotation false

```
player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```